# How to add character before string based on condition

Tags: python, if-statement, text, count, conditional-statements

I'm trying to add one or more character before a string if a condition (membership sold) has been met. The example:

```
Huurders verbijsterd over verduistering 596.00...             3
Horeca-echtpaar Bas en Beaudine over verwoeste...             2
Nieuwe coronabesmettingen in Hillegom: ’Wak...                2
Monsters en demonen komen tot leven op dak Koe...             2
Hoofddorp krijgt een stadspark in het centrum,...             2
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add an asterix before each string (headliner), corresponding to the amount of sales. I've tried many variations of code including the one below.

```
df['article_title'] = '*' + df['article_title'] if df[df['Transactions'] == 1] else df['article_title']
```

Quite frankly: I can't seem to execute this quite simple command. Hopefully this community can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think "==1" should be out of the square brackets.

```
df['article_title'] = '*' + df['article_title'] if df[df['Transactions']] == 1 else df['article_title']
```